# Reference SSRS assemblies w/o referencing specific SSRS server

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am trying to create a library that holds some utilities that facilitate SSRS reporting inside either winform or .net framework websites.

I have used the code on 2 projects, now looking to use it on a third. that's about the time i usually stop and break the code out into something reusable.

My issue is that I need to make a couple references to SSRS classes

```
 Public Warnings() As SSRS_E.Warning = Nothing
 Public credentials() As SSRS_.DataSourceCredentials = Nothing
```

The SSRS_E reference resolves to SSRS_ReportExecution2005
and the SSRS_ reference resolves to SSRS_reportservice2010

These are valid in my old projects because I have service references to a specific SSRS service.

Is it possible to locate these assemblies outside of a specific installation?

I do not want to get into a situation where I have to 'fix' the reference everytime I open the utility dll in a different project...

Comment: I am trying to 're-use'  about 30 lines of code.   Copy/paste is an option here, just trying to stay DRY if possible.

Comment: Did any library references get added to your existing projects when you added the service reference(s)? If so, they'd be the ones you need to add to any other project too.

Comment: not really. it wants to be a web reference. to be honest, i have looked at a couple articles on webReference v. serviceReference and decided to move on w/ my day.  one seems to simply wrap the other.   

The web reference references a WSDL which does not reference assemblies, it references a SOAP definition on the MS site.  I guess i should try pointing to that MS location and see if it can serve as a generic location...